# How i can stop this discord bot command wihout restart the bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How i can stop this discord bot command wihout restart the bot?

```
@bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, *args):
    response = ""
    for arg in args:
        response = response + " " + arg
    while True:
        await ctx.channel.send(response)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a variable

```py
bot.some_var = True

while bot.some_var:
    await ctx.send(response)
    if 'some condition met':
        loop = False
```

If you wanna stop the loop in a command:

```py
bot.some_var = True

@bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, *args):
    response = ' '.join(args)

    while bot.some_var:
        await ctx.send(response)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
   bot.some_var = False
```

Also two things:

1. You can simply `str.join(list)` instead of that weird for loop you made
2. use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep` so your code doesn't get blocked